# Run default react app on a custom Razor page For ASP.NET 2.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, razor-pages, asp-net-core-spa-services

I am using Vs 2017 template to create a React App with ASP.Net Core 2.1 . 
By default when i run the app it somehow runs on the default index page.

How do i make the same react app that runs on index page run on a custom razor page ?

For Example :
By default runs on https://localhost:32323 instead run on https://localhost:32323/Sample